# In-App Purchase Sandbox env is not working

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes, sandbox

I am trying to test In-App purchase in sandbox env, but it's not working, it asks for a password many times but and always returns failed transaction or sometimes responds with "IAP Error: cannot connect to iTunes store", it was working 2, 3 days before.

Comment: the app is not live yet, so I'm using the sandbox environment

Comment: @KishanBhatiya yes I am still facing the issue

Comment: I have the same issue, how to fix it? Code suddenly stop to work.

Comment: you fixed the issue?

Comment: @RRN Not yet, still searching for the solution.

Comment: any solutions so far? I started a thread here as well - I get the "Cannot connect to iTunes store" error as well. Made a post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64407864/revenuecat-getting-this-error-consistently-in-sandbox-there-is-a-problem-with/64409151#64409151

Comment: @TheFlyingDutchman, still searching, raised a ticket to Apple, waiting for updates from their side.

Comment: Thanks Aman. BTW - if you update to iOS 14, it works. It looks like they regressed sandbox for older iOS versions, when they released iOS 14.

Comment: @TheFlyingDutchman, Thanks. Mine is also started working after upgrading to iOS 14.0.1

Comment: May be due to intermittent issues with Apple's Sandbox environment that you have no control over. See:
https://www.google.com/search?q=There+was+a+problem+with+the+App+Store+error+RevenueCat&oq=There+was+a+problem+with+the+App+Store+error+RevenueCat
https://support.revenuecat.com/hc/en-us/articles/360046399333-App-Store-STORE-PROBLEM-error
https://docs.revenuecat.com/discuss/5d6cd49434b48f001c51efd4
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661351

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, the solution was to update the test device to iOS 14.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this gist code that I have used in past months, it works with dev environment and live environment for AppStore release. You can expand the IAPService with methods that your app needs. Check gist code:

https://gist.github.com/egzonpllana/abd6d385bb45b1e329fe85a624ee531f

Comment: I am using the same method for performing purchase and it was working 2 days before, today it stopped working suddenly, I am using sandbox users for purchasing, my in-app products are not live now.

Comment: Sad to hear that, I have read that sometimes sandbox does not work (very rare to happen). I wish you find a solution asap.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this temporary error is from the Apple sandbox side. Still getting the same "Cannot connect to iTunes store" error for IOS 13 devices. I manage to test the same code on IOS 12 iPhone device and the in-app purchases working well there (No Issue).

Comment: @AmanParashar check the same application code on IOS 12 and let me know if I can assist you further.
Thanks

Comment: so it seems the issue only happen on IOS 13? IOS 12 and 14 has no issue?

Comment: I have iOS 12.4.8 but still i'm facing same issue

Comment: @KishanBhatiya Sorry to hear that. Is the same code working previously(Around 5-6 days ago)? My code was working perfectly on 14th, on all IOS devices, but now it is only working for IOS 12 only.

Comment: @UmairAhmed, I already tried on iOS 14, iOS 13 both, but it's not working in both of them. let me try this in iOS 12 too.

Comment: Hi, am having an issue with iOS 15, it asks for an apple id and password, which if I don't provide, the appStoreReceiptURL path does not exist in the device problem happens. Did anyone get the solution for it?