# RevenueCat - Getting this error consistently in Sandbox "There is a problem with the app store. Cannot connect to iTunes store"

Tags: revenuecat

My RevenueCat integration was working in Sandbox for a week and suddenly stopped working with the error above. Its been broken for several days now and I am not sure if this is due to a config issue on my end or if Apple's sandbox is just broken. I am using the Flutter SDK.

I tried the following:

1. Created new sandbox accounts
2. Checked that all agreements and taxes are done (I see "Active" in the paid agreements section)
3. I checked to make sure that my subscription products were "Ready to submit" and were not missing any metadata
4. I created a new app in App Store connect and did everything from scratch.

Is there anything else I should try? See the image below for the experience.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoxT5.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" (although without Revenue Cat). The solution was to update the test device to iOS 14.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the App Store `/verifyReceipt` endpoint affecting every developer, regardless of whether they're using RevenueCat or not. There's unfortunately nothing you can do.

Comment: Ah! is it an ongoing issue now? Are there any threads on this from Apple? I just wanted to make sure that this is affecting everyone and not something specific that i did. Great relief!

Comment: BTW - unrelated comment: RevenueCat has been awesome so far! Great product. Only comment on pricing: I wish there was a 99$ plan where we get ad attribution stuff until 10K MRR. That would be awesome and I'd buy it in  a heartbeat.

Comment: I work on support at RevenueCat and there's been a TON of reports about this recently, there's definitely something up on Apple's side. It doesn't seem to be a sustained outage (which we've seen before) just extreme instability. P.S. - Thanks for the pricing feedback, feel free to share any feedback or feature requests with the RevenueCat team directly, it's always good to hear.

Comment: @enc_life , maybe you should tell Apple about this issue. We are all small developers, Apple won't listen to us, if RevenueCat talk to Apple, I think Apple would really try to fix the issue. Thanks.